# MySQL Crashing in the connect function

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I have x64 bit, downloaded the 32 bit (That because there is few error with the lib files, so I have to use the 32 bit)
Did everything here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html#connector-cpp-application-build-dynamic

But the program crashing at the 'connect'function:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/25478716.jpg/

What to do?
here is the source code of what I'm trying to compile.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
//__declspec(dllexport)
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' » AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "pass");//
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: dopn't you specify connection string?

Comment: Weird, but in VS 2008 its working .. I can make it work also in this VS12 ?

Answer (score 0):

you may try to construct connection in different way:

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// just going to input the general details and not the port numbers
struct connection_details
{
    char *server;
    char *user;
    char *password;
    char *database;
};

MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details)
{
     // first of all create a mysql instance and initialize the variables within
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    // connect to the database with the details attached.
    if (!mysql_real_connect(connection,mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      printf("Conection error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
      exit(1);
    }
    return connection;
}

MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, char *sql_query)
{
   // send the query to the database
   if (mysql_query(connection, sql_query))
   {
      printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
      exit(1);
   }

   return mysql_use_result(connection);
}

int main()
{
  MYSQL *conn;      // the connection
  MYSQL_RES *res;   // the results
  MYSQL_ROW row;    // the results row (line by line)

  struct connection_details mysqlD;
  mysqlD.server = "localhost";  // where the mysql database is
  mysqlD.user = "mysqlusername";        // the root user of mysql   
  mysqlD.password = "mysqlpassword"; // the password of the root user in mysql
  mysqlD.database = "mysql";    // the databse to pick

  // connect to the mysql database
  conn = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);

  // assign the results return to the MYSQL_RES pointer
  res = mysql_perform_query(conn, "show tables");

  printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
      printf("%s\n", row[0]);

  /* clean up the database result set */
  mysql_free_result(res);
  /* clean up the database link */
  mysql_close(conn);

  return 0;
}
```

[see here](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/02/17/mysql-connection-example/) full example